# How to export Bibtex of many papers from ACM?

Tags: bibtex, acm

I'm doing a [systematic review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_review) and need do download citations of more 300 papers from [ACM](http://dl.acm.org/).

Is possible do this automatically?

Comment: I don't see the link here to TeX

Comment: agreed with @JosephWright about the link to tex.  however, nelson beebe at the university of utah maintains bibtex-encoded bibliographies of a large number of journals, including many acm "sig" journals.  these bibliographies can be found at ftp://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/bibnet/journals/

Answer (score 1):

ACM has BibTeX entries for their papers, including several custom fields. But be warned, the quality tends to horrible, I have been able to use very few as they come, most needed extensive editing. They don't handle complex names right (I write "Last, First Middle" always to help sorting that out, they use just "First Middle Last", and that tends to get messed up). They use strange abbreviations for journals, for which I haven't been able to find definitions. Dates are scrambled on occasion. It looks like this is generated automatically from the papers, badly.

In any case, presumably you'll spend a lot more time reading, analyzing, and categorizing the paper than the trivial time in picking up the BibTeX entry with the electronic copy...